# Why is "similarity" more specific than "equivalence"?

Tags: matrices, terminology

At least regarding matrices, we have

- $A$ is similar to $B$ if $\exists S: B=S^{-1}AS$
- $A$ is equivalent to $B$ if $\exists P,Q: B=Q^{-1}AP$

I am confused about the usage of the terms "similar" and "equivalent". I would have thought that equivalence is more specific than similarity, i.e. equivalence is a special case (subset) of similarity. However, the above indicates the other way around.

How can this be explained? Is this specific to linear algebra, or is this a math-wide phenomenon?

Comment: @GudsonChou I think my question is, why are mathematicians driving on the wrong side of the road?

Comment: Well, similarity (as defined for matrices) is certainly an equivalence relation ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes. But I would expect it to be the other way around. In a non-math context, if two things are "equivalent", then they are also (completely) "similar". This is not the case in the above matrix example. Why is this relationship reversed in math?

Comment: Agreed, in real-life, similarity fails to be transitive. Whereas the math notion of equivalent exactly captures its etymolgy ("having the same value" - for each equivalence relation $\cong $ on $X$ there is a function $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $x\cong x'\iff f(x)=f(x')$, i.e., $x$ and $x'$ have the same value under $f$), similarity somewhat fails to match this. Then again, what could be the suggestion to handle nomenclature of a possibly infinitely fine-grained stack of equivalence relations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are simply different concepts.

*Similarity* is a property related to endomorphisms on a vector space $V$. Two matrices $A, B$ are similar if they represent the same endomorphism $f: V \to V$ on picking bases $\mathcal{B}_A, \mathcal{B}_B$ of $V$ and taking the map with respect to the two bases respectively.

*Equivalence* is a property related to linear maps between pairs of spaces $V, W$. Two matrices (representing maps $f, g: V \to W$) are equivalent if we can pick an "input basis and an output basis" for each of $f, g$ such that $f, g$ have the same matrices with respect to those two pairs of bases respectively.

Both "similarity" and "equivalence" are equivalence relations, but they're on different spaces. Similarity is a sub-relation of equivalence.

In general, I'm not aware of other instances where "similarity" and "equivalence" relate to each other at all.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ and $B$ are similar  if they represent the same endomorphism $f$ of a finite dimensional $K$-vector space $E$ in different bases. Thus similar matrices are equivalent, but  the converse is false:

They're similar if and only if they have the same *Jordan normal form*, and also if and only  if they have the same *similarity invariants*, which the *invariant factors* of $E$, seen as a $K[X]$-module  through $f$ (i. e. for any $v\in E$, $\;X\cdot v=f(v)$).

On another hand, $A$ and $B$ are *equivalent* if and only if $\;\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}B$.